# Count id from other table using sub query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to count id's of student according to the specified batches. The student id resides in other table. What I'm trying is to fetch details of all batches from dbo.Batches that contains batchid. At the same time i want to count the number of students enrolled in that batch. The studentid and the batch id is in dbo.studentbatchrelation table. What i've tried so far is, applied sub query to generate deatils of the batches as well as the number of students enrolled in the particular batches.

Below is my query:

**Query**

```
(Select 
     Count(studentId) as TotalStudents 
 from 
     dbo.StudentBatchRelation 
 where 
     BatchId in (Select 
                     b.Id as BatchId, b.CourseId as CourseId, 
                     b.BatchNumber as BatchNumber,
                     b.BatchTimingsFrom as BatchTimingsFrom, 
                     b.BatchTimingsTo as BatchTimingsTo, 
                     b.BatchDuration as Duration, b.BatchDate as BatchDate,
                     b."Days" as "Days", b.CourseRoomId as CourseRoomId,  
                     c.CourseName as CourseName, 
                     cr.RoomName as RoomName, 
                     cr.RoomCapacity as RoomCapacity 
                 from 
                     dbo."Batches" b, dbo.Courses c,
                     dbo.CourseRooms cr 
                 where 
                     b.CourseId = c.Id 
                     and b.CourseRoomId = cr.Id 
                     and b.ActiveBatch = 1  ));
```

**Table Structure for Batches**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Batches] (
    [Id]               VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    [CourseId]         VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    [BatchNumber]      VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    [BatchTimingsFrom] TIME (7)      NOT NULL,
    [BatchTimingsTo]   TIME (7)      NOT NULL,
    [BatchDuration]    VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Days]             VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    [CourseRoomId]     VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    [BatchDate]        VARCHAR (250) NULL,
    [ActiveBatch]      BIT           DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Batches] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_BATCHES_COURSE] FOREIGN KEY ([CourseId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Courses] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_BATCHES_CourseRoom] FOREIGN KEY ([CourseRoomId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[CourseRooms] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

**Table Structure for StudentBatchRelation**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentBatchRelation] (
    [Id]              VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    [BatchId]         VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    [StudentId]       VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    [TransactionId]   VARCHAR (250) NULL,
    [RemainingAmount] VARCHAR (250) NULL,
    [Status]          VARCHAR (250) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_StudentBatchRelation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentBatchRelation_Batch] FOREIGN KEY ([BatchId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Batches] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentBatch_TransactionId] FOREIGN KEY ([TransactionId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TransactionTable] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentBatchRelation_Student] FOREIGN KEY ([StudentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id])
);
```

Comment: Please give your table structured using a fiddle

Comment: can i write table structure in the question?

Comment: Yes, you can. (Even better).

Comment: Please refer to my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

I could be better to use `join`;

```
Select 
     SBR.BatchId, Count(SBR.StudentId) as TotalStudents 
 from 
     dbo.StudentBatchRelation SBR 
     inner join Batches B ON SBR.BatchId = B.Id
     inner join Courses C ON C.Id = B.CourseId
     inner join CourseRooms CR ON CR.Id = B.CourseRoomId
     where B.ActiveBatch = 1
     group by SBR.BatchId
```

Comment: how would this query generate the details of the batches?

Comment: select the Batches fields; "select B.Id, B.CourseId" etc

Comment: Could you please write full query against your given answer. That would be better for me to understand

Comment: I think, you should do it your own. Because I couldn't know your complete requirements. We help you about the key features which you can use in your purpose. And the join is best important feature in your case now.

Comment: I tried your query but it gives me an error. Like i followed your query after TotalStudents with b.Id as batchid .... but it gives me an error with "Column 'Batches.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function "

Comment: I updated the answer. Perform grouping and select them (my example is SBR.BatchId) and make an aggregate function. (Count(SBR.StudentId))

Comment: Your query is returning total students, however when there is no student in the batches, it doesn't show details of that batch.

Comment: So, you should use the left join instead of inner join for possible not matching Student records

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    b.Id as BatchId, b.CourseId as CourseId, 
    b.BatchNumber as BatchNumber,
    b.BatchTimingsFrom as BatchTimingsFrom, 
    b.BatchTimingsTo as BatchTimingsTo, 
    b.BatchDuration as Duration, b.BatchDate as BatchDate,
    b."Days" as "Days", b.CourseRoomId as CourseRoomId,  
    c.CourseName as CourseName, 
    cr.RoomName as RoomName, 
    cr.RoomCapacity as RoomCapacity 
    ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY b.Id) countstudentinBatches
from 
dbo."Batches" b 
INNER JOIN dbo.Courses c ON b.CourseId = c.Id  
INNER JOIN dbo.CourseRooms cr ON b.CourseRoomId = cr.Id 
INNER JOIN dbo.StudentBatchRelation sr ON sr.BatchId = b.Id
WHERE b.ActiveBatch = 1
```

Comment: In this query b.ActiveBatch is fulfilling the criteria.

Comment: Do you need more changes to the query, sorry the comment is not clear to me.

Comment: In your query, "where b.ActiveBatch = 1" is not full fulling the criteria.

Comment: So you want all the count of the students without checking for where b.ActiveBatch = 1. ?

Comment: I do want to check, its not resulting as expected.